# Uncaught Error: Command timed out in imagemagick npm package

Tags: windows, imagemagick, node-imagemagick

So I am trying to read the meta data of EXR files using Imagemagick npm package and it works fine on smaller files, but on larger files I am getting this error

Uncaught Error: Command timed out

I tried editing the policy.xml and increased the time, but still not working. Any workaround or how to fix this?

Comment: What did you set the timeout value to? How long does it run before timing out?

Comment: What command were you using? How big is your EXR file? Are you running on a Raspberry Pi Zero or something?

Comment: I set it to 600 just to be sure if it would work or not.

Comment: I'm using identify and the exr is about 600MB also not running on a rasberry pi.

Comment: On a side note the same piece of code got executed once but after extracting the metadata of like 2-3 exr's it gave the same error.

Comment: Could you try and be more specific so folk can help you please? How long does it run before timing out? What command were you using - `identify` has tens of options, some of which must read and analyse the entire image. Have you tried running the same command outside of `node` in the Command Prompt? How long does it take there? Have you limited the RAM ImageMagick can use?

Comment: I am just using im.identify without any options and saving the whole json object i get